# Trouble accessing file in other directory using Ajax, am I specifying the path wrong?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, path, wamp

In WAMP I changed the root directory from `C:\wamp\www` to `C:\wamp\www\public`. I have a file named `username.html` it communicates through Ajax with `simple.php`. This works fine if `simple.php` is in `C:\wamp\www\public` but if I move it to `C:\wamp\www\private` nothing happens.

NOTE I elected not to use jquery and am doing this with plain javascript.

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "simple.php?suite="+top,true);//works when simple.php is in same folder

xmlhttp.open("GET", "..\private\simple.php?suite="+top,true);//doesn't work

xmlhttp.open("GET", "../private/simple.php?suite="+top,true);//doesn't work

xmlhttp.open("GET", "..//private//simple.php?suite="+top,true);//doesn't work
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because now, public is your webroot and you are requesting the site from the webserver. The "private" directory is out of the reach of your webserver, because is out of the webroot. You can access it directly from your PHP script (i.e. via fopen(), include, require,... if it is allowed in security settings), but webserver can not serve it directly.

Comment: Is there anything that can be done if I don't want the public to be able to see `simple.php`?

Comment: I think you need to write more about your use-case. As for myself, I would try to simply require() the simple.php script from "private" directory (i.e. by calling require (dirname(\_\_FILE\_\_).'/../private/simple.php') with proper parameters set beforehand, if I really wanted to go this path. But to be honest, I would rather create a function of whatever the script does and include the code and call the function directly. But maybe, you have some specific use case.