# scripts aren't run now that they are not in webroot, so how to run them and keep the private from the www

Tags: security, webserver, authentication

I'm making a website where users must log in to view certain content. I accomplished this by setting the server root to `C:\WAMP\www\public` and putting all the files that users must be logged in to see in a different directory (i.e. `C:\WAMP\www\private`). How can a logged in user access the files in the private directory if it's not on the web server? Through a require.

```
<?php
session_start();
$destination = $_GET['d'];
if(isset($_SESSION['loggedInUser']))
    require '../private/'.$destination;
else
    require 'signinrequired.html';
?>
```

but there's a problem. If I require a script then it won't be interpreted since it's not in the web root ([as explained in the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14763416/trouble-accessing-file-in-other-directory-using-ajax-am-i-specifying-the-path-w)). So how do I fix this or completely redesign the system?

Resolution: I got confused and made up a non-existing problem. It is possible to separate the HTML from the PHP by storing the HTML files not in the server root (aka web root, whatever it's called) and including them using PHP files that are in the server root. Since the HTML files are not interpreted (are not scripts) this works. Since PHP files are interpreted by the server they must be in the server root, but since they are interpreted (and the source code isn't just given to the client) the client can't see the inerworkings of the program. If anyone else somehow got confused as I did then hopefully I explained a bit to unstuck them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why wouldn't you just have all your private content within the web root and do something like this on each  private page;

```
<?php 
   if(!$logged_in){ header("Location:restricted.php"); exit;}
?>
```

Comment: Because every file would need to contain PHP and then you couldn't have any plain HTML files. Though it may be worth it. Thanks

Comment: @Celeritas: Users can not directly access files outside of the public html folder over HTTP, so you will need to do something like Steve suggests. However, your public HTML/PHP files could read your private/static HTML files (from your private folder) and serve them to the client.

Comment: @Celeritas You're probably better off picking a language(/file extension) and sticking with it. If a particular file doesn't need any actual PHP in it at the moment, whatever. Even if what you're trying to do worked, consider the eventuality that one of your HTML files later ends up needing a bit of PHP. Not only do you having to move the file, but your URL is changing(*.html -> *.php), existing links need to be updated, if you even control them, etc.

Answer (score 0):

As a quick and dirty solution, you could use a combination of `.htpasswd` and an Apache alias. As a solution this is not very scalable - you would have to manually maintain a list of usernames and create a password for them that you send in plaintext. Fine for, say, an internal document repository.

If you want something more dynamic and scalable, then your current approach will provide very weak protection whatever you do. Your better off dropping in, say, [Symfony's security bundle](https://github.com/symfony/Security) or even using a CMS like Drupal.